How to use the API to set Custom Properties field values for a GitHub repo
I am trying to programmatically loop through a set of repos and set Custom Properties on each, so I can better filter them using other GitHub APIs. Here is my Python code that tries to make updates to the GitHub repository's Custom Properties:
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github+json',
    'Authorization': "Bearer " + os.getenv('GITHUB_APIKEY'),
    'User-Agent' : 'python script', 
    'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
}
request_url = f"/repos/{github_Org}/{repo_name}/secret-scanning/alerts"
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.github.com")                 
custom_properties = '''{
        "properties": [     
        {"property_name": "Owner-of-repo", "value": "BH"},
        {"property_name": "Intented-Purpose", "value": "Open-Source"}
    ]
}'''
conn.request("PUT", request_url , custom_properties, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
response_data = response.read()
conn.close()
json_data = json.loads(response_data.decode("utf-8"))


The problem is the response always returns a (404) Not Found. But when I list the repos using another API but same API key, I can see the repo. Based on some trial and error, I believe the backend is complaining about the payload of the PUT request.

why are you PUT to a secret scanning url?

this looks like the endpoint you want: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/custom-properties?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-custom-property-values-for-a-repository

Daniel is correct, the GET verb needed to be a PATCH, not a PUT.
